# Zabbix. How use function as of parameter another function

Tags: zabbix

Idea use computed property to get difference between first day of month and current.
I use formula:
`last("prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.2") - last("prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.2", dayofmonth("prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.2") )`
first part work properly, but then i use dayofmonth i get error

> Cannot evaluate expression: unexpected token at ")".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from zabbix forum [thread link](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?p=209002#post209002)

> Sorry, but you can not use last function in such way, it does not
>   support another last function as argument
>
> the possible workaround - just create an item with scheduled interval
>   :
>
> https://www.zabbix.com/documentation...stom_intervals
>
> interval will be something like this:  Code: md1h0m0  every 1st day of
>   each month at 0:00 This value will be collected only once a month and
>   will represent your prtMarkerSuppliesLevel at the begining of the
>   month.
>
> then you can use last(your.current.item) - last(scheduled.item)
>
> Regards, Kaspars